# How to avoid killing child process early?

Tags: c, process, child-process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX_PIDS 28

volatile pid_t *pids;

void kPid(int x)
{
    int c;
    for (c=0; c<10; c++) {

    if (pids[c] == x)
    {   
        int status = 0;
        pids[c] = wait(&status);
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }
  }
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int c;
  pid_t pid;
  pids = mmap(0, MAX_PIDS*sizeof(pid_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
              MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  memset((void *)pids, 0, MAX_PIDS*sizeof(pid_t));
  for (c=0; c<10; c++) {
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
      exit(1);
    } else if (pid < 0) {
      perror("fork failed");
    } else {
      pids[c] = pid;
    }
  }

  int t;
  char test[50];
  snprintf(test,sizeof(test),"ps -ef | grep defunct",pids[c]);
  system(test);
  printf("Kill child: ");
  scanf("%d",&t);
  kPid(t);
  system(test);
  exit(0);
}
```

Now when i use command:
snprintf(test,sizeof(test),"ps -ef | grep defunct",pids[c]);

It shows that processess are defunct, how to avoid this? i know that "exit(1);" kill the process but what can i put instead of this?
I want to be able to kill the process later

Comment: Are you asking how to make the children not die, or how to make them not be defunct when they do die?

Comment: "I want to be able to kill the process later" certainly seems to indicate he wants the children to not die, but his comments on the (first, so far) answer cast some doubt on that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to avoid defunct processes is to ignore SIGCHLD:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

Otherwise, wait for the child termination with waitpid(). It mainly depends, if you want to know when a child is terminated and what its exit code is. If you do not need that information, go with the signal-method

Comment: where to put that line? ( signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);) and how to prevent of infinite loop when i delete this line => exit(1)

Comment: You can do that right after the start of the main function. Do _not_ delete the exit(1).

Comment: This seems to miss the point.  He says, I think, he wants the child processes to *not die* (yet), not that he wants to ignore them when they do die.

Comment: after that i not see any process :) i want to create child processess, list them and next select one PID to die... and next list again.

Comment: I thinks sleep(1000) does not solve the problem because i dont see the processess... snprintf(test,sizeof(test),"ps -ef | grep defunct",pids[c]); is not good for that?

Comment: Either the processes are up and running (can be killed) or defunct. Both at once is not possible

Comment: @Ctx, yes, a `sleep()` call was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: probably sleep works but why do not I see active processes?

Comment: Because you are probably still looking wrong... Best would be to output the pid of the forked childprocess in the main process and look that up in the process table. Or grep for the process name. But do _not_ grep for _defunct_

Comment: @rovio, you say you are grepping the process list to select entries with "defunct" in them.  If you do that, then why do you expect to see processes that are not defunct and do not have the literal text "defunct" somewhere on their command line?

Comment: My mistake, I missed it... ok but now when i start program it shows "Kill child:" and now i it stop the program ... because of this (sleep(1000))